# Полностью просмотренное видео youtube

Tags: html, jquery, youtube

Можно ли как то отследить, полностью ли пользователь просмотрел видео?(дошёл до конца) и только после этого открывать блоки? Используя jq

Comment: какие блоки? где закрывать?

Comment: да любые jq действия выполнять после просмотра видео

Comment: т.е. у Вас просто ролик во фрейме на странице ?

Comment: `var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
alert(vid.ended);`
HTML5 видео.

Comment: верно, ролик в iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, используя Iframe API и событие `onStateChange`.
Событие `onStateChange` вернет 0, когда воспроизведение окончено.
Правда, если Вам нужно, чтобы пользователь посмотрел обязательно всё видео, то тут перемотка не учитывается, то есть 0 будет возвращен, когда видео дойдет до конца, не важно перематывал его пользователь или нет.

---

Подробнее про Iframe API и события можно почитать тут:

- API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=ru
- События -
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=ru#EventHandlers

```js
// Загружаем Iframe API
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

//Добавляем видео в элемент с ID player
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onReady //Функция, которая вызовется когда видео загружено
        }
    });
}

function onReady() {
    //Событие onStateChange вернет 0 когда воспроизведение окончено
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
        console.log('State is:', e.data);
        if(e.data == 0){
           //Выполняем нужные действия  
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```